# How to get hostname in gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I am trying to get a hostname in an utility file that i written in gatsby project. But it throws error like this

`WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined`

**Utility File:**

```
export const getHostName = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' || typeof document !== 'document' ) {
    return window?.location?.hostname || document?.location?.hostname;
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can fix this error. Or any other alternative that we can use it here to get the hostname

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
export const getHostName = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return window?.location?.hostname || document?.location?.hostname;
  }
}
```

The second part of the condition is being validated almost always and it's breaking your code.

Keep in mind that the `getHostName` function should be called inside the React lifecycle method (`useEffect` for example) or it won't display anything.